# Logstash grok filter : parsing custom application logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

**I'm trying to parse my application logs using logstash filters. The log file contents are like below**

```
17 May 2016 11:45:53,391 [tomcat-http--10] INFO com.visa.vrm.aop.aspects.LoggingAspect - RTaBzeTuarf |macBook|com.visa.vrm.admin.controller.OrgController|getOrgs|1006
```

I'm trying to create a dashboard (line chart) using logstash and want to show the activities on it. For e.g request comes in from some server with correlation id and have to see which class it calls with corresponding method and how long it took to execute.

The message is like:

```
correlation id | server-name | class name | method name | time taken
log file e.g 
RTaBzeTuarf |macBook|com.visa.vrm.admin.controller.OrgController|getOrgs|1006
```

I'm unable to create **grok patterns/filters** for above message. Can someone advise me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
(?<timestamp>%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}) \[%{NOTSPACE:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<logger>[A-Za-z0-9$_.]+) - %{GREEDYDATA:correlationId}\|%{GREEDYDATA:servername}\|%{GREEDYDATA:className}\|%{GREEDYDATA:methodName}\|%{NUMBER:time}$
```